# Interpretation of a question concerning "ordered bases"

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If I am asked to find the number of *ordered bases* of a finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb F_p$, what does that mean? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the number of linearly independent $n$-tuples of vectors, if the space has dimension $n$. It is the same as the number of $n\times n$ invertible matrices over $\mathbb F_p$ because any two bases are related by one of those.

Answer (score 0):

It just means that $\{a,b,c\}$ is counted separately from $\{a,c,b\}, \{c,a,b\}$ etc.